# C# : Filtering a DataGrid that binds from a DataTable that gets data from MySQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Here is my C# code

```
private DataTable MyDT= new DataTable();

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    fillUpList(); //Fills up my DataTable by sending queries to MySQL Server
    myGrid.ItemsSource = StMatID.DefaultView;            
}
```

And here's my XAML code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            filter:DataGridExtensions.UseBackgroundWorkerForFiltering="True"
            filter:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False"
            filter:DataGridExtensions.IsFilterVisible=
              "{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=ShowHideFilterCheckBox, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ColumnHeaderStyle=
              "{StaticResource 
                  {ComponentResourceKey 
                     TypeInTargetAssembly=
                        {x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl},
                     ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
            Grid.Row="0">                        
</DataGrid>



            </Grid>
```

I'm using DataGridFilterLibrary http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering

What I'm trying to do is to filter dynamically each column of my DataGrid , but it seems that the DataTable is not compatible or something and I get NotSupportedException . The exception in coming from the QueryControllerFactory.cs of DataGridFilterLibrary , line 26 at `if (view != null) view.Filter = null;` . Here is a screenshot too [image] Any idea ?

Comment: A NotSupportedException does not necessarily mean that your DataTable is not compatible. It means that you tried to do something like call a method that is not supported. But since you did not say where the exception is coming from, it's going to be really hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn I just edited my question , thanks for the response.